# copying all the certificates from keystore to a temp directory explicitly

Tags: java, keystore, keytool

I have one certificates installed in java and I can execute this command under the JRE security director:

```
   keytool -list -keystore cacerts
```

That gives me the list of installed certificates, now what i am trying is that all the certificates that are listed under this command to be copied in a folder named temp and this temp folder i have created under in unix at the following

`location /opt/app/temp/`

so please advise how can i opy all the certifactes from keystore to a folder named temp

Comment: Why would you want all the root CA certificates extracted? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Andreas well I want to check the validity of each certificate plus I need the certificates copy for an audit

Comment: Unless you've modified cacerts, that's a file shipped with Java. But to export them, use the `-exportcert` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to dump the output to file the following command will work:

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts >> /opt/app/temp/<filename_here>
```

For verbose:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts >> /opt/app/temp/<filename_here>
```